# Javascript doesn't work on elements added by jquery's load(), prepend(), or append() functions

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a comment system where a user submits a comment, the comment is processed, then the HTML for the comment is returned. jquery then adds that retrieved HTML to the comment system. that whole system works, but the comment buttons that requir javascript do not work unless I refresh the page. How do make my javascript work on elements added through load, prepend, or append?

Not sure if my question is clear, but here's the javascript I have:

```
$(function () {
  $(".replyform").submit( function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr("id").split('_')[1];
    text = $('textarea#text_'+id).val();
    $.post( "/api/add/comment/", {_csrf: _csrf, id: id, text: text, a: a},
      function (data) {
        $('#commentreplies_'+id).prepend(data);
        $('#replyform_' + id).hide();
    });
  });
});
```

I then have elements such as "reply" for each comment that have functions in an external javascript that do not work unless I refresh the page. Hopefully that made sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (it is deprecated, see [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) function

Comment: As commented on another answer: I changed `$(".replyform").submit( function (event) {` to `$(".replyform").on("submit", function (event) {` just to test on() but it messes up my entire javascript code (ajax no longer works). what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like variable scope problem. Check $(this) object in your callback.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a `live` method to allow elements that are added on the page after loading to be able to have events already bound by jQuery. You can bind your events using live method as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

A second solution, and probably a more efficient one, would be using `delegate` method to handle events by existing containers and delegating them to the elements inside that container. You can read more about delegate [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

An example solution using `live` method is as follows assuming you have buttons with class 'reply' in your response data:

```
  $(".reply").live('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     id = $(this).attr("id").split('_')[1];
     text = $('textarea#text_'+id).val();
     // post won't work since url is missing, but that code remains the same.
     // Assuming you get a response like this
     // <div><input type="textarea" id="text2" /><input type="submit" id="reply_2" value="submitReply" class="reply" /></div>
     // And if you append this to your document
     var data = $('<div></div>').html('<input type="textarea" id="text2" /><input type="submit" id="reply_2" value="submitReply" class="reply" />');

     $('#commentreplies_'+id).prepend();
     $('#reply_' + id).hide();
  });
```

Comment: I tried doing this with on() (since live() is apparently deprecated) and it seems to break my javascript: `$(function() {
  $(".report, .reportnav").click( function() {
    id = $(this).attr("id").split('_')[1];
    document.getElementById("reportid").setAttribute("value", id);
    $('#modal-report').modal({
      show: true,
      keyboard: true,
      backdrop: true,
    });
  });
});`

vs. `$(".report, .reportnav").on("click", function() { ... })`

Comment: I added comment below about `on` method being introduced with jQuery 1.7, sorry I didn't see your comment here. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I created an example on fiddle, can you check whether that is what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/melih/8DsYU/

Answer (score 2):

There are few different approaches to this

1) Explicitly init the button inside returned HTML on AJAX success

2) Setup global handler for your button type using jQuery `live()` function (replaced by `on()` in 1.7)

3) define button handler right in the markup

Which one do you pick is really up to your specific task.

Comment: I changed `$(".replyform").submit( function (event) {` to `$(".replyform").on("submit", function (event) {` just to test on() but it messes up my entire javascript code. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @JonathanOng Messes up in what way? Try changing that to `$("#your-reply-container-box").on("submit", ".replyform", function(e) {...})`

Comment: i'm trying to google an example for 1), but I can't find any. care to share some links, please?

Comment: by messing up, i mean the ajax no longer works. your suggestion doesn't seem to work either. =/